# How would I print the largest number from a user input (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to make it so that the user can input as many positive numbers as they want but when a negative is inputted it ends the loop and outputs the largest number inputted.

This is what I have so far

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

while (num >= 0):
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

if (num < 0):
    print("Largest number entered: " + str(num))
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How to output the largest number that was inputted into the terminal

Comment: Do you know that there is a function called `max`? You should research what it does and how you can use it.

Comment: The values which the user inputs are not being captured. Therefore, the max number cannot be determined, as only the current value is being stored.

Comment: @mkrieger1 he doesnt have to hold all inputs as list because of memory concerns.

Comment: @S3DEV his problem is about the logic i guess. He doesnt know how to do that (:

Answer (score 1):

Like that i guess

```
maxnum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if num < 0: break   
    maxnum = num if num > maxnum else num

if (num < 0):
    print("Largest number entered: " + str(maxnum))
```

Comment: `while num >= 0` will give error, since num isn't declared before. But I like your approach :D

Comment: Yup, i didnt checked it in an editor and never run. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: And you can remove the if statement `if (num < 0):` outside the loop, since `num` will actually be negative there ;)

Comment: Better to break in loop ;)